# Android Authenticator and FB

Tags: android, facebook-authentication, android-authenticator

I have an app which do the canonical email/password login and signup to the server.

Note: I need to do the login / auto-login every time the user open the app.

Now I want to add login/signup with fb.

Currently I'm using the android Account manager with a custom authenticator where I save mail and password. If a user log in with fb I will not have any password to save in the account: I have to save something else instead or I'll leave that field empty? In the latter if I'll add another auth system as Twitter how can I know to which system the user belong?

Speaking about the server, which data I'll have to send to it to authenticate Fb users? I thought about the couple email/id, but it doesn't seem too strong to me...

Thank you for your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how can I know to which system the user belong

Use SharedPreferences in order to save which system the user belong to:

```
public static int TWITTER_ACCOUNT = 0;
public static int FB_ACCOUNT = 1;
onLogin(){
   if(fb){
         SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences(context);
         sp.edit().putString(PREF_ACTIVE_ACCOUNT, FB_ACCOUNT).apply();
   }
}
```

> which data I'll have to send to it to authenticate Fb users

Why not sending the `access_token`?

> If a user log in with fb I will not have any password to save in the account

Just keep the access token. you should use fb access token to get data from FB or login to your system. have a look at `oauth2`

Also do note that you are missing the point if your users need to login each time the app starts

To save user data in `AccountManager` use:

```
public void setUserData(final Account account, final String key, final String value) 
public String getUserData(final Account account, final String key)
```

Comment: I didn't mention SP purposely, I cannot believe that there isn't a system to save all user account's data in the account manager.

I talked about login and AUTOlogin. I need to authenticate the user to my server every time to update the GCM token for push notifications.

Comment: i don't understand your comment. if you don't want to use SP then you should mention it in your question. you can save user data in AccountManager using `public static final String KEY_USERDATA = "userdata";`